# Using WRT-54G as repeater after flashing with DD-WRT?

Tags: dd-wrt, wrt54g

Can I use my WRT-54G as a wireless repeater after flashing with DD-WRT?

Comment: Its worth adding the model - not all WRT54Gs are made the same. Versions older than 4, and GLs are usually the most troublefree for reflashing.

Comment: @slhck I have done it. I thought it was well known... I tried using RaspberryPis for doing this, but they are always too slow, in this age of 802.11n and 802.11ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @slhck comment, here I go:

Yes you can, it is a very standard affair, check here: [this Web page of the DD-WRT user manual](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater).